# How to remove/supress warning "Remote Identification Change is not verified" in Airflow?

Tags: ssh, airflow

Error:

```
[2019-04-11 10:08:44,005] {{ssh_operator.py:80}} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2019-04-11 10:08:44,015] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-04-11 10:08:44,014] {{base_hook.py:83}} INFO - Using connection to: id: conn_box2. Host: aws13shi02.logitech.com, Port: 22, Schema: None, Login: phonrao, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: {'timeout': '10', 'compress': 'false', 'no_host_key_check': 'false', 'allow_host_key_change': 'false'}
[2019-04-11 10:08:44,016] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-04-11 10:08:44,016] {{ssh_hook.py:155}} WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2019-04-11 10:08:44,022] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2019-04-11 10:08:44,022] {{transport.py:1746}} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.2p2)
```

how do I remove/suppress this WARNING -

```
WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
```

Answer (score 0):

**https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/connection/ssh.html** says

allow_host_key_change - Set to true if you want to allow connecting to hosts that has host key changed or when you get ‘REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED’ error. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks. Other possible solution is to remove the host entry from ~/.ssh/known_hosts file. Default is false.

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to do this, you have to modify your .ssh/known_host to remove the identification of your host.
You can remove the file (not recommanded), or use the ssh-keygen command (ssh-keygen -R hostname)

But before doing this, ask yourself what your identification changed. This means that the IP you are trying to reach is not linked to the same server as before. It can be totally normal (if you use a static IP on cloud, linked to a new server), or can be the sign of a man-of-the-middle attack.