# SSH between AWS and GCP with paramiko

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, sftp, paramiko

I am running the following code to send some files via SFTP from GCP to a server on AWS

```
import paramiko
import os
from airflow.contrib.hooks.ssh_hook import SSHHook

hook = SSHHook(remote_host="host.amazonaws.com",
               username="username",
               password="password")

hook.pkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("keyfile")
conn_id = hook.get_conn().open_sftp()
```

When I run it locally on my computer evrything works and the SFTP connection is established. As soon as I move it to GCP and run as a task in Cloud Composer I get the following error:

`WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks\n[2021-12-23 16:48:07,391] {ssh_hook.py:171} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This wont protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/venva41v8tku/script.py", line 29, in <module>\n    res = make_sftp(*args, **kwargs)\n  File "/tmp/venva41v8tku/script.py", line 27, in make_sftp\n    conn_id = hook.get_conn()\n  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/contrib/hooks/ssh_hook.py", line 194, in get_conn\n    client.connect(**connect_kwargs)\n  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 412, in connect\n    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()\n  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 834, in get_remote_server_key\n    raise SSHException("No existing session")\nparamiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session\n'`

How can I get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your local machine has the server's host key stored in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file, while the GCP machine does not have it.

I do not think this is Paramiko question. It probably how the SSHHook handles the host keys.
See also [How to remove/supress warning "Remote Identification Change is not verified" in Airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55630678/850848)